# Dots in path name

Tags: directory, filenames

I am receiving an error from an application I am running.

The error looks like this:

```
john@john-replacement:~/Desktop/yarbu-1.4.8/bin$ sudo yarbu-engine --VERBOSE
/usr/local/bin/yarbu-engine: line 996: cd: /usr/local/bin/../../etc/yarbu/conf/default: No such file or directory
```

What do the dots mean in `/usr/local/bin/../../etc/` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `../` is notation for "the parent directory" so, in the case you presented:

`/usr/local/bin/../../etc/yarbu/conf/default`

The system will resolve that as:

`/usr/etc/yarbu/conf/default`

It's the same as if you were in the directory `/usr/local/bin` and you then typed `cd ..` twice, you would now be in the `/usr` directory.

You can verify this yourself:

```
$ cd /usr/local/bin
$ pwd
/usr/local/bin
$ cd /usr/local/bin/../../../
$ pwd
/
```

Comment: It's not the same as `cd ..`, which sanitizes the path using `realpath`. If one of the path components of `/usr/local/bin` is a symbolic link which points somewhere else, then `realpath` sanitization will not point to the same directory. e.g. if `/usr/local` is a synlink to `/opt/unspecified`, `/usr/local/bin/../../etc/yarbu/conf/default` is resolved as `/opt/etc/yarbu/conf/default`, but `realpath` sanitizes it as `/usr/etc/yarbu/conf/default`. Just nitpicking here. In contrast, `ls ../../etc/yarbu/conf/default` while in `/usr/local/bin` works.

Comment: Good point @BatchyX it's not exactly the same... I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to gabe's answer, which is nice:

The unix command readlink will always return the real path of a file or directory: `readlink -f /usr/local/bin/../../etc/` will return `/usr/etc/`.

The command also resolves symbolic links. For example on my system, `readlink -f /usr/bin/java` returns `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7.15-oracle-x64/jre/bin/java`. Both use cases are very helpful for scripts.

Btw: `..` (and also `.` which refers to the directory where you are) are *not* unix specific. The same will also work under at least all dos/windows, mac, linux/unix/bsd based operating systems.