# What means the dots on a path?

Tags: directory

How is `"/a/./b/../../c/"` equal to `/c`?

I saw this as a question on one of the Stack Exchange sites. Apparently `..` means to pop the stack(?). Why is this the case?

Comment: "Apparently .. means to pop the stack? why is this the case?", it is the case simply because that is how it has been defined. They could have used any symbols, really.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are ./ and ../ directories?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63081/what-are-and-directories) or [Dots in path name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59604/dots-in-path-name?rq=1)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Assume root looks like:

```
/a/b
/c
```

Let's break it down to componenets:
`/` -> root
`/a` -> in (a)
`.` -> THIS dir path
`/a/./` -> still in `/a`
`/a/./b` -> in `/a/b`
`..` -> go "up" one level
`/a/./b/..` -> `/a/b/..` -> `/a`
`/a/./b/../..` -> `/a/..` -> `/`
`/a/./b/../../c` -> `/c`

Answer (score 6):

In the *nix world, every directory is a child directory of a parent directory. Every directory has an implicit '.' directory that refers to itself, and an implicit '..' directory that refers to its parent. So if you're in a particular directory, and you *change directory* (`cd`) to '.' (commands starting with '$' can be run on your command line!), you'll stay in the same directory:

```
$ pwd
/tmp/a/b
$ cd .
$ pwd
/tmp/a/b
```

But changing directory to '..' goes up one:

```
$ cd ..
$ pwd
/tmp/a
```

And changing directory to '..' goes up again:

```
$ cd ..
$ pwd
/tmp
```

The only directory that is an exception to this rule is the *root directory*, which doesn't have a parent directory:

```
$ cd ..
$ pwd
/
$ cd ..
$ pwd
/
```

Check out [this tutorial on Unix directories](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Unix/unix1.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

/ is your root directory.
It has a directory structure like,

```
/ 
___ /c
___ /a
______/b (child dir of a)
___ /other dirs
```

Now , a single dot . means the same directory and double dots (..) Means the parent directory.

So in your example , when you use . in the path it stays in the same directory and when you use .. It jumps back to its parent directory. So eventually by jumping up, it reaches the root (/) so it's equivalent to /c